Cosmos db input string in not in correct format
when i try to delete the item from record using partition key.
error is arising that The input string '1bf23515-ccdc-446d-8b27-d8bdf4494e73' was not in a correct format.'
here is sample code
public async Task<bool> DeleteStudentAsync<T>(string partitionKey)
{
    try
    {
        var studentDetails = await GetByIdAsync<T>(partitionKey);
        foreach (var document in studentDetails)
        {
            if (document.partitionKeyValue != null)
            {
                PartitionKey partitionKeyValue = new PartitionKey(document.partitionKeyValue.ToString());
                await _container.DeleteItemAsync<dynamic>(document.id, partitionKeyValue);
            }
        }
    
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e);
        throw;
    }
}

public async Task<List<(string id, TPartitionKey partitionKeyValue)>> GetByIdAsync<TPartitionKey>(
string partitionKey)
{
    try
    {
        var sqlQueryText = new QueryDefinition($"SELECT c.StudentId, c.{partitionKey} FROM c");
        var idsWithPartitionKeys = new List<(string id, TPartitionKey partitionKeyValue)>();

        using var resultSetIterator = _container.GetItemQueryIterator<dynamic>(sqlQueryText);
    
        while (resultSetIterator.HasMoreResults)
        {
            var response = await resultSetIterator.ReadNextAsync();
            foreach (var document in response)
            {
                var partitionKeyValue = (TPartitionKey)document[partitionKey];
                idsWithPartitionKeys.Add((idValue, partitionKeyValue));
            }
        }
    
        return idsWithPartitionKeys;
    }
    catch (Exception a)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(a);
        throw;
    }

}

here idsWithPartitionKeys.Add((idValue, partitionKeyValue)); it is saying that input string id is not in correct format
am expecting to id's withpartitionKeys to delete an item
 here is the sample image of cosmos db
